# What UI components are used to add a list to the bottom of an EditText?

Tags: android, list, drop-down-menu, android-edittext, autosuggest

I have an EditText and an ArrayList of Strings. When the user starts typing some characters into the EditText I want to show a list of what the user might be typing.

I can do the String comparison and the rest, but I am wondering what UI objects I should use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks. I wonder why it's called a textview and not an edittext :s

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use AutoCompleteTextView for this .Follow links below
[AutocompleteTextview](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html)

[Developer link for AutocompleteTextview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)